# How to prevent timer from being throttled by Chrome when my webpage in background?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Last year, [Chrome shipped a feature to increase battery life by limiting JavaScript timer wake ups in background webpages](https://news.thewindowsclub.com/google-chrome-ships-a-new-feature-to-increase-the-battery-life-101417/).

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log('done')
}, 1000)
```

The code above will print logs after 1 second.But when the webpage is in background, it will print after about 10 seconds. It causes a lot of problems.

So, are there any solutions can prevent Chrome from throttling my timers?

Comment: Stupid Google, everywhere I read about battery life but what about desktop PCs? Oh, wait there is also the same stupid javascript throttling! Why? Since Chrome v88 throttling started after 5 minutes, later from Chrome v110 someone genius changed it to 10 seconds! Why it is not configurable in options? Why I can not set websites which I do not want to be throttled? Thanks for FireFox. We recommend our clients an many other SaaS applications to use Firefox instead of stupid Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try loading the script when the window is active, but if it can't be helped, [HackTimer.js](https://github.com/turuslan/HackTimer) is a good workaround using Web Workers.